# osx NSPopUpButton Notification after Selection

Tags: swift, macos, notifications, nspopupbutton

I need to know the user selection after the user changed the item from a `NSPopUpButton`.

Why on earth does the `NSPopUpButton` control has a notification before the user action.:

> Posted when an NSPopUpButton object receives a mouse-down event—that is, when the user is about to select an item from the menu.

Implementing the `NSPopUpButton` notification works fine:

```
@objc func popUpButtonUsed(notification: NSNotification){
    print(distributionPopUpButton.titleOfSelectedItem!)
}
```

But how can I trigger an action/method after the user selection?

Thanks!

Comment: Set an IBAction.  Isn't it that simple?

Comment: not for me. how do I trigger an action after users selection? thanks.

Comment: ok, ok, that's simple. Using an action is indeed calling the method after the user selection. Perfect. Thanks. Wasn't that obvious for me. Create an answer that I can accept your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like the following.

```
@IBAction func popUpButtonUsed(_ sender: NSPopUpButton) {
    print(sender.indexOfSelectedItem)
}
```